# the div in my grid is not lining up correctly

Tags: html, css, grid

the project is to recreate a Mondrian painting using Grid. My will not line up correctly, can someone tell me what I did wrong. If possible can you explain why their are 4 columns and rows instead of 2 and 3. and also positioning  when looking at the pic I see the ordering as R,W,W,W,Bl,W,Y,Bk,W but the teacher said it R,W,W,W,B,W,W,Bk

***this is my code***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  .grid-container{
      height: 748px;
      width: 748px;
      display: grid;
      background-color: black;
      grid-template-columns: 320px, 198px, 153px,50px;
      grid-template-rows: 414px, 130px, 155px, 20px;
      gap: 9px;
    }

    .child{
      background-color: #F0F1EC;
    }


    .red{
      background-color: #E72F24;
    }

    .white1{
      grid-column: span 3;
    } 

    .white2{
      grid-row: span 2;
    }

   .white3{
     grid-area: 2 / 2 / 4 / 4
    }

    .white4{
      grid-row: span 2;
    }

    .blue{
      background-color: #004592;
      border-bottom: 10px solid #000;
    }

    .yellow{
      background-color: #F9D01E;

    }

    .black{
      background-color: #232629;

    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="red child"></div>
    <div class="white1 child"></div>
    <div class="white2 child"></div>
    <div class="white3 child"></div>

    <div class="blue child"></div>
    <div class="white4 child"></div>

    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="yellow child"></div>
    <div class="black child"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

***and this is the solution***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        .container {
          height: 748px;
          width: 748px;
          display: grid;
          background-color: #000;
          grid-template-columns: 320px 198px 153px 50px;
          grid-template-rows: 414px 130px 155px 22px;
          gap: 9px;
        }

        .item {
          background-color: #F0F1EC;
        }

        .red {
          background-color: #E72F24;
        }

        .white1 {
          grid-column: span 3;
        }

        .white2 {
          grid-row: span 2;
        }

        .white3 {
          grid-area: 2 / 2 / 4 /4
        }

        .blue {
          background-color: #004592;
          border-bottom: 10px solid #000;
        }

        .white4 {
          grid-row: span 2;
        }

        .yellow {
          background-color: #F9D01E;
        }

        .black {
          background-color: #232629;
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>

     <div class="container">
        <div class="item red"></div>
        <div class="item white1"></div>
        <div class="item white2"></div>
        <div class="item white3"></div>

        <div class="item blue"></div>
        <div class="item white4"></div>

        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item yellow"></div>
        <div class="item black"></div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the columns and rows are determined by `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` respectively. There are 4 numbers, which is why there are 4 rows/columns, and the value is the height/width.

As for why they look different, it's because the `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` values had commas in them, they should only be spaces.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  .grid-container{
      height: 748px;
      width: 748px;
      display: grid;
      background-color: black;
      grid-template-columns: 320px 198px 153px 50px;
      grid-template-rows: 414px 130px 155px 20px;
      gap: 9px;
    }

    .child{
      background-color: #F0F1EC;
    }


    .red{
      background-color: #E72F24;
    }

    .white1{
      grid-column: span 3;
    } 

    .white2{
      grid-row: span 2;
    }

   .white3{
     grid-area: 2 / 2 / 4 / 4
    }

    .white4{
      grid-row: span 2;
    }

    .blue{
      background-color: #004592;
      border-bottom: 10px solid #000;
    }

    .yellow{
      background-color: #F9D01E;

    }

    .black{
      background-color: #232629;

    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="red child"></div>
    <div class="white1 child"></div>
    <div class="white2 child"></div>
    <div class="white3 child"></div>

    <div class="blue child"></div>
    <div class="white4 child"></div>

    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="yellow child"></div>
    <div class="black child"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```